# How should I access to overwritten variable in overwritten function?

Tags: javascript

I'm not able to understand of how should I get to particular variable `a` in next code:

```
var a = 1;
console.log(a);

function local() {
  var a = 2;
  console.log(a);
  function local() {
    var a = 3;
    console.log(a);
    function local() {
      var a = 4;
      console.log(a)
    }
    local();
  }
  local();
}
local();
```

I know this is artificial example but I can't go to sleep without the answer :)

So how should I get a particular variable `a` from any of overwritten function?
Thanks.

Comment: Variables declared within a function's scope using `var` are bound to that function scope - you cannot access them outside of the function scope (unless you return them)

Comment: "Doctor doctor, it hurts when I do this." "So don't do that".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a variable in the local scope with the same name as a variable in a higher scope, the new declaration hides the higher scoped variable and there is NO way to access that higher scoped variable from the local scope.

This is just how Javascript is designed.  There isn't some magic way around it.  If you want access to the higher scoped variable, then don't declare a local variable with the same name.  Pick a different name.

If the top-most variable is in the global scope, then you might be able to access that variable with a global prefix such as `window.a` or `global.a` (depending upon which environment you're running in).  But, the intermediate variables that are not in the global scope are not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

you can access global variables by the `window` object like this

```
var aa=11;
function my_func(){
    var aa=22;
    alert("local: "+aa+" global: "+window.aa);
}
```

but there is no way of accessing the local variables outside the function, as they do not really exist out there!